# Detectar cambio de fecha usando datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

Busco la manera de hacer un "Sumador automatico de Dinero"; por ejemplo; Me levanto un día, prendo el pc y automaticamente se suman 10$ a un archivo. Mi problema está haciendo parte de un codigo para determinar que *el día de hoy no es el mismo de ayer* y no lo sume cada vez que lo abra si no al detectar el que hoy no se ha agregado dinero. Por lo tanto tengo este codigo de la función que no me compila:

```
from datetime import *
def checkIfSaving():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    alreadyStored = False
    in_file = open("checktime.txt", "rt") ; contents = in_file.read() ;ct = contents
    f=open('checktime.txt','rt');
    if contents != today:
        addMoney() ; alreadyStored = True
        f.write(today) ; f.close()
```

Sólo por esta parte del codigo el programa no logra compilar. Como ven lo escrito con `if contents != today:` intento hacer que agregue el dinero si no es el día de hoy... 
La manera que uso para detectar si hoy no es el mismo día de ayer es detectando la fecha, sí es distinta entonces no necesitará cambiarla Y si la cambia ag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer error es que `datetime.date.today` no existe tal y como estás importando. Lo que es más importante, no importes usando wildcard (`*`) nunca excepto para un puñado de casos en los que está justificado, es una mala práctica. Reduce la legibilidad del código (propiciando errores como este entre otras cosas), puebla el espacio de nombres principal sin necesidad alguna y puede causar conflictos con identificadores del espacio de nombres principal causando su enmascaramiento y los consiguientes errores, a veces silenciosos.

Si importas mediante `import datetime` puedes llamar al método `today` de la clase `date` del módulo `datetime` sin problemas mediante `datetime.date.today()`. Si importaras como haces tú (no recomendado) o mediante `from datetime import date` debería ser  `date.today()`.

Por otro lado, `datetime.date.today` retorna un objeto `datetime.date` no una cadena, no puedes hacer `f.write(today)` directamente, en todo caso debes hacer un casting explícito previo a `str`.

Por otro lado, no se muy bien que pretendes con la variable `alreadyStored`, es una **variable local** pero no la usas en ningún momento para nada en la función, aparte de asignarle valor.  Si es una variable global, tal y como lo haces no vas a modificarla globalmente (el cambio no se refleja fuera de la función), debes indicar que la trate como global antes de asignarle el valor  dentro de la función con `global alreadyStored`. Tal y como lo haces, aunque la variable esté definida globalmente, al asignarle un valor se crea una nueva variable local con el mismo nombre y la global no se modifica. Por lo general evita el uso de variables globales, es mejor que la función retorne `True` o `False` que hacer que modifique una variable global, fuente común de errores y de perdida de legibilidad del código.

Sin tener en cuenta a `alreadyStored` dado que no se que función tiene en tu  código, todo podría quedar así:

```
import datetime


def check_if_saving():
    today = str(datetime.date.today())
    with open("checktime.txt", "r+") as f:
        last_date = f.read()

        if last_date != today:
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(today)
            f.truncate()
            addMoney()
```

Solo se abre el archivo una vez y se usa el gestor de contexto vía `with` que se encarga de cerrar el archivo de forma automática cuando termina la ejecución de su bloque de código.

Te recomiendo mirarte las convenciones de estilo del código Python definidas en PEP-8, la legibilidad del código es un aspecto muy importante en Python:

- [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?) (Oficial, en inglés)
- [Guía de estilo para el código Python – PEP 8 en Español](http://recursospython.com/pep8es.pdf) (PDF, por www.recursospython.com)

Comment: Excelente, aunque la manera en que tu dices de importar datetime no me funciona. Al escribir `import datetime` el programa no compila. Igualmente, use la manera antigua, importé todo y apliqué `date.today()`.

Comment: @ChristianD'Albano el modo que muestro es totalmente correcto tanto en Python 2 como en Python 3, algo hay mal en tu código o proyecto si no te funciona, prueba online: https://repl.it/repls/PrestigiousEarlyDemos. En todo caso usa `from datetime import date` no `from datetime import *`. Te recomiendo que siempre muestres el error y la traza completa del mismo que te muestra, generalmente es bastante informativo y se te podrá ayudar mucho mejor que si solo comentas que no funciona. Un saludo.